# Растянуть блок DIV по всей высоте?

Tags: css

Имеется 3 блока **div** по горизонтали. Центральный блок расширяется за счет контента вниз.
Боковые блоки без контента остаются вверху. Как их растянуть на 100% с центральным блоком?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Qs6eA/1/

```js
var maxHeight = 0,
  $inlineDivs = $('.inline div');
$inlineDivs.each(function() {
  maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
});

$inlineDivs.css('height', maxHeight);
```

```css
.inline div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  background: orange;
  /* optional */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.inline div:first-child,
.inline div:last-child {
  background: green;
  /* optional */
}
```

```html
<div class='inline'>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    1234
    <br>1234
    <br>1234
    <br>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```